# Error with a simple Animation

Tags: android

I tried to start an AlphaAnimation for a ImageView with this code:

```
        ImageView view;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.prueba);

            view=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.icon);
            view.setAlpha(0x00);        
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
                    switch (e.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        Log.i("Down v", "x:" + e.getX() + " y:" + e.getY());
                        view.startAnimation(new AlphaAnimation(0x22, 0xFF));
    //                  break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        Log.i("Move", "x:" + e.getX() + " y:" + e.getY());
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        Log.i("Up", "x:" + e.getX() + " y:" + e.getY());
                        view.setAlpha(0x00);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
                        Log.i("Out", "x:" + e.getX() + " y:" + e.getY());
                        break;
                    default:
                        Log.i("None", "nada");
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.i("Click", "es un click");
                }
            });
        }
```

this code should be make the ImageView appear when is touched, but nothing happend.
Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the odd thing about the Android animations.

You're using `setAlpha()` to set the alpha of the view to 0.  At the same time you're using `AlphaAnimation` to set the alpha value to 1.  This *seems* like it would work.  The problem is they work on two different frameworks.  `setAlpha()` was introduced with Honeycomb in conjunction with [ObjectAnimators](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html) while `AlphaAnimation` has been around since Cupcake (possibly API 1 too, but I forget).  ObjectAnimators change the actual property of the View while the AlphaAnimation simply changes how the view is drawn (confused yet? :P).

Anyway, `AlphaAnimation` doesn't effect the alpha property of the view like you think it would.  It's animating the View from 0 to 1, but the property is still 0 thus it's still invisible.

You have two options here.

Keep `setAlpha()` the way it is and use `ObjectAnimators` like so:

```
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "alpha", 0f, 1f);
anim.setDuration(1000);
anim.start();
```

This is the easiest and preferred method.  It only works in API levels 11+ though.  If that's desired, then go for it.

The other option is to remove `setAlpha()` and pre-animate the view to `0` with a duration of `0`.  Call `setFillAfter(true)` on the animation before you start it.  This will make sure it stays invisible (it may be true by default, but I don't remember).

I hope that made sense.